# How to wait for javascript function response?

Tags: javascript, facebook, function, wait

I'm making webpage using facebook API.

I want to show user's friends in webpage.

So I code like this

```
function showFriends(){
    var result = getFriends();
    for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
        //show friends in webpage
    }
}

function getFriends(){
    FB.api( {
    method: 'fql.query', 
    query: 'SELECT uid, name, pic_square  FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())'}, 
    function(response) {
    return response;
        }
    );
}
```

Problem is this : getFriends function need a little time, so for loop processes before getting response of getFriends. And I don't want to locate for loop in getFriends function because getFriends function will be used in many other function.

So is there any solution to wait function's response?

Comment: Put the loop in the callback perhaps.

Comment: Why not calling a function that has the loop from the callback function?

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a callback. http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the `showFriends` function as a callback.

```
function showFriends(result){
    for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
        //show friends in webpage
    }
}

function getFriends(callback){
    FB.api({
      method: 'fql.query', 
      query: 'SELECT uid, name, pic_square  FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())'
    }, 
    callback
  );
}

getFriends(showFriends);
```

Comment: Why don't I think like this? Thanks!

Comment: @GFbahamut If it's worked, you should accept this answer as the correct answer.